# Converting readable time to unix time with Python

Tags: python, sqlite, date, time

I am building a kind of calender web app

I have set up the following form in HTML where the user set up an event/appointment.

The data the user has entered then goes into python.

I would like to be able to store the date they have entered as a unix time stamp inside a SQLite database, while displaying it as readable dates when needed.

Are there any way I can quickly convert between the two?

```
               <form method="post" action="/writeEvent">

                    <div>
                     <label>Year ("yyyy") <span class="required">*</span></label>
                     <input name="year" type="text" id="year" value="" />
                    </div>

                    <div>
                     <label>Month ("mm")  <span class="required">*</span></label>
                     <input name="month" type="password" id="month" value="" />
                    </div>

                    <div>
                     <label>Day ("dd") <span class="required">*</span></label>
                     <input name="day" type="password" id="day" value="" />
                    </div>

                    <div>
                     <label>Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
                     <textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="30"  id="message" value="" ></textarea><br /><br />
                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <input type="submit"  value="Submit" class="button">
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button">
                    </div>


                </form>
```

EDIT:
I haven't got any python code per se, apart from me trying things out in the terminal.

I have tried using `localtime()` to give me a human readable time. However, this is given in the format of

```
(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=3, tm_hour=19, tm_min=9, tm_sec=13, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=94, tm_isdst=0)
```

I tried to extract out just the year, month and day by first assigning it to a variable by doing

```
newTime=time.localtime()
```

But an error message comes up saying invalid syntax on the equals sign. It appears i can't assign the result to a variable.

I have also tried using mktime() to generate a time stamp. However when i do

```
timeStamp = time.mktime(2012,04,03)
```

I am confronted with an error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: mktime() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

So now I don't know what to do next, any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything on the python side? Could you show us what you have so far? This is just the web form.

Comment: @jdi I haven't really done much on the python side except testing things in the terminal.
I read that time.localtime() is suppose to convert unix time to readable time. however, the output is in the form of "(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=3, tm_hour=19, tm_min=9, tm_sec=13, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=94, tm_isdst=0)" and I don't know how to extract out just the year, month and day. as `testTime = time.localtime()` result in syntax error

Comment: Well if you don't have any existing python code to show, then the most you will probably get is links to the time or datetime module api docs

Comment: @jdi Additionally, i read the mktime() is suppose to convert readable time to unix time. But when i try mktime(2012, 04, 03). It tells me mktime() only takes one argument. and that I've given it 3

Comment: All of this needs to be in your question

Comment: @jdi Thank you, I just added them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time.mktime()` is giving you that error because what it expects is a 9-item long tuple, which is one argument, whereas you are giving it 3 ints.

There are a couple ways to take your year, month, day values and turn them into a unix timestamp.

First, since you only have the 3 elements, it might be easiest to use the [datetime module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html):

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 10)
```

Once you have this datetime object, you can convert it to epoch time in a few ways. If you want to work in terms of this being UTC time, you can convert it to a UTC timetuple, and then use the [calendar module](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html) to convert it to epoch:

```
timetuple = dt.utctimetuple()
epoch = calendar.timegm(timetuple)
```

If you are working with local time, then you could do this part using the [time module](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html)

```
timetuple = dt.timetuple()
epoch = time.mktime(timetuple)
```

As @Here You Go suggested in his answer, if you can just store your string in sql and let it  handle the date conversions as a real date type, that would be preferable and I wil defer to his answer for that route.

To get back to a datetime object from a utc timestamp you can do:

```
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(epoch)
```

And a datetime object lets you access all of its individual components:

```
dt.year
dt.month
dt.day
```

For simple string formatting, you can create a string like this:

```
dateString = "%s-%s-%s" % (year, month, day)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store it as a string and do no conversion?  sqlite will still let you do date math:

```
SQLite version 3.7.10 2012-01-16 13:28:40
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> CREATE TABLE dates (the_date TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO dates VALUES ('2012-09-13 02:13');
sqlite> INSERT INTO dates VALUES ('2012-10-01 01:15');
sqlite> INSERT INTO dates VALUES ('2012-10-16 08:42');
sqlite> SELECT MIN(the_date) FROM dates;
2012-09-13 02:13
sqlite> SELECT MAX(the_date) FROM dates;
2012-10-16 08:42
sqlite> SELECT the_date FROM dates ORDER BY the_date;
2012-09-13 02:13
2012-10-01 01:15
2012-10-16 08:42
sqlite> SELECT DATE(the_date, '+1 year') FROM dates ORDER BY the_date;
2013-09-13
2013-10-01
2013-10-16
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you, I didn't know you can do date maths! Now how would i go about putting today's date into that format? Cause I was hoping my server would check every appointment with today's date and delete whatever outdated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datetime and time module from the standard library to do this.

```
from datetime import date, datetime

# Create a date object from the form fields
appointment = date(day=20, month=12, year=2013)

# Return a unix time stamp from it
stamp = appointment.strftime('%s')

# Create a datetime object from a time stamp
now = datetime.fromtimestamp(stamp)

# Returns a prettily formatted string of the datetime object
print now.strftime('%H:%M - %A the %d of %B')
# See the docs here 
# http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior 
# for additional options provided for strftime
```

Now, you can do it  this way. But seeing as you are using Python you might want to think about storing datetime objects in the database as time tuples or or capturing timezone information with tz aware datetime objects.